# Python-like keyword arguments via pgfkeys

Tags: pgfkeys

I like to define commands to denote multi-parameter (mathematical) functions, e.g., `\myf{x}{C}` expands to `f(x;C)`.  During writing, however, it is sometimes hard to remember if I should use `\myf{x}{C}` or `\myf{C}{x}`, so I would like to use something like keyword arguments from Python.  In my example, this means I would like to write `\myf{set=C,at=x}` or `\myf{at=x,set=C}` and get `f(x;C)` as the result for both commands.  For that, I am using pgfkeys; see below.

I am running into an error when pdflatexing the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\pgfkeys{
  /myf/set/.estore in = \myfset,
  /myf/at/.estore in = \myfat,
}
\newcommand*{\myf}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \pgfkeys{/myf/.cd, #1}
  f(\myfat;\myfset)
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\(\myf{set=\mathscr{C},at=a}\)
\end{document}
```

I get an error

```
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.16 \(\myf{set=\mathscr{C},at=a}
                                 \)
?
```

This error goes away if I replace `\mathscr{C}` with `C` or if I drop the package `mathtools` (which I need for other features).

Could anybody please help me fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `.estore in` rather than just `.sotre in`? The former does expansion which may (and here does) go wrong with non-expandable input.

Comment: @JosephWright: the only reason is my ignorance.  Thank you so much.  This solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun a solution using `l3keys`. Here, the keys `set` defaults to `\mathscr{A}` and `at` to `c`, so you can use `\myf{}` with an empty argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { mk1 }
 {
  set .tl_set:N  = \l_mk_set_tl   ,
  at  .tl_set:N  = \l_mk_at_tl    ,
  set .default:n = { \mathscr{A} },
  at  .default:n = { c }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand { \myf } { m }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { mk1 } { set,at,#1 }
  f( \tl_use:N \l_mk_at_tl ; \tl_use:N \l_mk_set_tl )
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\(\myf{set=\mathscr{C},at=a}\)
\(\myf{}\)
\end{document}
```

> [image]